# jQuery .attr() not setting attribute

Tags: jquery

I have yes/no radio buttons that ask the user if they watch sports. If they mark yes, then the user is required to check the sports that apply.  If the answer answers no, then the section is not required.

My code works fine if the user marks yes or no then hits enter.  But the problem comes when the user changes from yes or no.  If the user first marks no and then marks yes, there's no required attribute.  If the opposite happens, then required attribute is there.  Please see below for the html and jquery.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```js
function selectatleastOne() {
  var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
  requiredCheckboxes.each(function() {
    this.setCustomValidity('Please select all that apply');
  });
  requiredCheckboxes.on('change', function(e) {
    var checkboxGroup = requiredCheckboxes.filter('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]');
    var isChecked = checkboxGroup.is(':checked');
    checkboxGroup.prop('required', !isChecked);
    checkboxGroup.each(function() {
      if (!isChecked) {
        this.setCustomValidity('Please select all that apply');
      } else {
        this.setCustomValidity('');
      }
    });
  });
}
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input:radio[name="yes_no"]').change(
    function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'yes') {
        $('[name="sport[]"]').attr('required');
        selectatleastOne();
      } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'no') {
        $('[name="sport[]"]').removeAttr('required');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
  <fieldset>
    <hr>
    <h4>Do you watch or play sports?
      <span class="yes_no" id="yes_radio"><input type="radio" name="yes_no" value="yes" required="required"> Yes</input></span>
      <span class="yes_no" id="no_radio"><input type="radio" name="yes_no" value="no" required="required"> No</input></h4></span>
      <div>
        <p><i>If yes, select all that apply:</i></p>
        <span class="selectall_clear" id="select_all">Select All</span>
        <span class="selectall_clear" id="clear">Clear</span></div>
      <br>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Athletics"  required="required"> Athletics</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Badminton" required="required"> Badminton</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Basketball"> Baseball</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Boxing" required="required"> Boxing</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Cricket" required="required"> Cricket</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Cycling" required="required"> Cycling</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Field_Hockey" required="required"> Field Hockey</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Football" required="required"> Football</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Formula_1" required="required"> Formula 1</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Golf" required="required"> Golf</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Gymnastics" required="required"> Gymnastics</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Handball" required="required"> Handball</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Ice_Hockey" required="required"> Ice Hockey</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="MMA" required="required"> MMA</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="MotoGP" required="required"> MotoGP</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Rugby" required="required"> Rugby</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Skiing" required="required"> Skiing</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Snooker" required="required"> Snooker</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Soccer" required="required"> Soccer</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Swimming" required="required"> Swimming</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Tennis" required="required"> Tennis</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Table_Tennis" required="required"> Table Tennis</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Volleyball" required="required"> Volleyball</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Wrestling" required="required"> Wrestling</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Other" required="required"> Other</label><br>
      </div>

  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <button type='submit' name='submitted_questions' id='submit_questions'>Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: First, "repair" your HTML code. Is invalid. Then focus on JS.

Comment: What part is invalid, please?

Comment: Try your HTML code with w3 validator. You will be surprised.

Comment: You've got a couple of mis-nested tags, and checkboxes are self-closing so don't need a `</input>`.  None of that is relevant to your question however, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The main problem I can see here is that every time the user clicks "Yes" you attach a set of change handlers to every required checkbox -- but you never remove those handlers.  When the user clicks "No" you remove the `required` attributes, but the existing change handlers are still here. When the user clicks "Yes" again there are now *two* change handlers on every checkbox.

Comment: (It's also not necessary to do `if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'yes')` -- you don't care about the `:checked` state, just the value is enough.  But that's just redundant, not broken.)

Comment: Yes, can anyone please tell me what I can do to fix this?  I'd greatly appreciate it...

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, Waldemarice and Daniel Beck.

Comment: After the change() function I wrote to remove the attribute, so why is it still there?  And when a user marks 'yes,'  I specified to add the attribute, so why isn't it there?  Somebody please help....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add the 'required' attribute to input on change of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365911/how-can-i-add-the-required-attribute-to-input-on-change-of-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't the "required" attribute being set correctly?  Because when the user clicks 'yes' you're calling

```
$('[name="sport[]"]').attr('required');
```

which returns the current value of the attribute.  You want to *set* the attribute, though so you should call this instead:

```
$('[name="sport[]"]').attr('required', true);
```

(That only appeared to work on the first click because the attribute is set by default, so the first click on "Yes" wouldn't have done anything anyway.)

```js
$('input:radio[name="yes_no"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'yes') { // not necessary to check the :checked state here too
    $('[name="sport[]"]').attr('required', true);
  } else {
    $('[name="sport[]"]').removeAttr('required');
  }
});
```

```css
input:required {
  outline: 2px solid #F00/* so we can see the results easily */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Do you watch or play sports?
  <span class="yes_no" id="yes_radio"><input type="radio" name="yes_no" value="yes" required="required"> Yes</input></span>
  <span class="yes_no" id="no_radio"><input type="radio" name="yes_no" value="no" required="required"> No</input></h4></span>


  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Athletics" required="required"> Athletics</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Badminton" required="required"> Badminton</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Basketball" required> Baseball</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Boxing" required="required"> Boxing</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Cricket" required="required"> Cricket</label><br>
  </div>
```

A more substantial problem is with your event handlers in `selectatleastOne()` -- it attaches a new change handler to every `$(':checkbox[required]')` every time the user clicks "Yes", but it never removes those change handlers -- so they'll still fire if the user has clicked "No", and if the user clicks "Yes" twice they'll fire twice for each input.

You could continue to manually add those handlers every time, as long as you remove them with `$(...).off('change')` when the user clicks "No", but instead of constantly binding and unbinding the same handler, it would be easier to just write a single permanent event handler that uses the checkboxes' required state to decide whether to do anything:

```
$(':checkbox').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).attr("required")) {
    // User has clicked "yes", do your validation
  } else {
    // User has clicked "no", so do nothing
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I added $(':checkbox[required]').off('change'); and I still get the error message.

Comment: The issue that I'm currently having is when going from 'yes' to 'no'...

Comment: That would really depend on where you added the `.off()` -- but again it'd be better to not do it that way; instead just have a single always-bound event that tests the 'required' attribute.